# Using vDSP_biquad as a one pole filter

Tags: accelerate-framework

I'd like to be able to use the vDSP_biquad function as a one pole filter.

My one pole filter looks like this :

```
output[i] = onePole->z1 = input[i] * onePole->a0 + onePole->z1 * onePole->b1;
```

where

```
    b1 = exp(-2.0 * M_PI * (_frequency / sampleRate));
    a0 = 1.0 - b1;
```

This one pole works great, but of course it's not optimized, which is why I'd like to use the Accelerate Framework to speed it up.

Because vDSP_biquad uses the Direct Form II of the biquad implementation, it seems to me I should be able to set the coefficients to use it as a one-pole filter.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_biquad_filter#Direct_form_2

```
filter->omega = 2 * M_PI * freq / sampleRate;
 filter->b1 = exp(-filter->omega);
 filter->b0 = 1 - filter->b1;
 filter->b2 = 0;
 filter->a1 = 0;
 filter->a2 = 0;
```

However, this does not work as a one pole filter.  (The implementation of biquad is fine, I use it for many other filter types, it's just these coefficients don't have the desired effect).

What am I doing wrong?

Also open to hearing other ways to optimize a one-pole filter with Accelerate or otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula [in the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate/1450374-vdsp_biquad_createsetup) is:

`y[n] = b0*x[n] + b1*x[n-1] + b2*x[n-2] - a1*y[n-1] - a2*y[n-2]`

In your above code, you're using `b1` which is two inputs ago. For a one-pole, you'll need to use the previous output, `y[n-1]`.

So I think the coefficients you want are:

`a1 = -exp(-2.0 * M_PI * (_frequency / sampleRate))`

`b0 = 1.0 + a1`

Comment: Thanks.  Took me a minute to sort out, but there is a tiny error.  Because a1 is negative here, it needs to be b0 = 1.0 + a1

Comment: @olynoise Fixed :)